# Firebase storage limit access to two users

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I've got folders in my firebase storage like this:

```
userid1_userid2/image.bmp
```

OR

```
userid2_userid1/image.bmp
```

How do I grant access to those images only to users with userid1 or userid2? I tried several things but the documentation is not really clear to me.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: match /{folder}/{file} {
     allow read: if folder.matches('request.auth.uid.*) || 
    folder.matches('.*request.auth.uid.*');
    }

Tried this and didn't work, tried several combinations but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using these rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{path}/{spath} {
      allow read,write: if path[0:28] == request.auth.uid || path[29:57] == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```